# BibTeX, natbib: weird (wrong?) order of the bibliography database fields in the final output?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

MWE for the problem I encountered:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
Some text here. \citep{Meier1992}
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

where the file 'references.bib' contains the following:

```
@INCOLLECTION{Meier1992,
  author = {Meier, U.},
  title = {Strengthening of Structures},
  booktitle = {Prestressing of Concrete},
  publisher = {Blackie Academic},
  year = {1992},
  editor = {Clarke, J.L.},
  pages = {153--171},
}
```

Compiling this produces (something like) this:

> Meier, U.(1992). Strengthening of structures. In Clarke, J., editor,
>   *Prestressing of Concrete*, pages 153–171. Blackie Academic.

while I was expecting something like this:

> Meier U,(1992) ‘Strengthening of structures’, In *Prestressing of*
>    *Concrete*, ed. J L Clarke, Blackie Academic,pp 153–171.

If you notice, the problem is the reversed placement of the `editor` and `booktitle` fields. Instead of:

> ...In `booktitle`, `editor`...

the order is:

> ...In `editor`,`booktitle`...

which looks weird to me. Can this be fixed?

P.S.: TeXLive 2011, Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, It can be fixed. I modified the file `chicago.bst` to allow you to obtain the desired result. Unfortunately the file is too big to paste it here; you can find it [here in pastebin](http://pastebin.com/bGpSifRv). Please save the file with the name `myrefs.bst` in a directory where TeX can find it (your current working directory, for example) and, in your document, use

```
\bibliographystyle{myrefs}
```

Delete all auxiliary files and process your document in the usual way. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mybibtest.bib}
@INCOLLECTION{Meier1992,
  author = {Meier, U.},
  title = {Strengthening of Structures},
  booktitle = {Prestressing of Concrete},
  publisher = {Blackie Academic},
  year = {1992},
  editor = {Clarke, J.L.},
  pages = {153--171},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
Some text here. \citep{Meier1992}
\bibliographystyle{myrefs} 
\bibliography{mybibtest}
\end{document}
```

And here's the result:

[image]

Comment: Can you specify what need to be modified in the `.bst` file? I'm using `apalike` for my thesis, so I would modify that one. Thanks.

Comment: Following this suggestion I solved the issue by modifying line #573 of `apalike2.bst` (for the apalike2 citation style only, off course) from `{ "In " eho.format.editors * ", " * booktitle emphasize * }` to `{ "In " booktitle emphasize * ", " * eho.format.editors * }`.

Answer (score 4):

When I run your MWE, I get neither the result you report getting nor the result you say you would like to get, but instead something rather different:
[image]

E.g., no quotation marks around title, year at end instead of after author, first names' initials *before* last names for both author and editor, page information before publisher, ...

In other words, it looks like you need a completely different bibliography style from `plain.bst` (or `plainnat.bst`) in order to achieve your objectives. I recommend you run latex on the file `makebst.tex`; this file should be in your TeXlive2011 distribution. It's a completely menu-driven system which asks you a lot of questions about how you would like to have your bibliography formatted. Its output will be a new `.bst` file that will generate a bibliography according to your formatting wishes. Suppose the file is called "newrefs.bst"; you should invoke it with the command `\bibliographystyle{newrefs}`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, After re-reading my question I realized that I didn't point out that besides the wrong order of `booktitle` and `editor` I was satisfied with the rest, so I don't need to modify most of the output. However, I am curious of how `makebst` works, so I will try that later today.